# Swift Codable support for objects represented as array

Tags: swift, rest, codable

I'm trying to encode and decode data from an API that represent an object as an array of strings, for instance:

```
[
  ["username", "message", "date"],
  ["username", "message", "date"],
  ["username", "message", "date"]
]
```

This is the corresponding Codable struct:

```
struct Message: Codable {
    let user: String
    let content: String
    let date: String

    private enum CodingKeys: Int, CodingKey {
        case user = 0
        case content = 1
        case date = 2
    }
}
```

Neither encoding or decoding work; encoding shows that a JSON object is created instead of an array:

```
let msg = Message(user: "foo", content: "content", date: "2019-06-04")

let jsonData   = try! JSONEncoder().encode(msg)
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
```

The final string is:

```
{"content":"content","user":"foo","date":"2019-06-04"}
```

My goal is to obtain the following string

```
["foo", "content", "2019-06-04"]
```

Using a custom encode/decode method in the struct solves this, but forces to create a lot of boilerplate for each struct/class.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    let values = try container.decode([String].self)
    user    = values[CodingKeys.user.rawValue]
    content = values[CodingKeys.content.rawValue]
    date    = values[CodingKeys.date.rawValue]
}
```

How would one proceed to support this for any object?

And yes, this is a weird API, but this is not the first time I encounter one of those and user a different API format is not what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Are you talking about encoding or decoding here, I  am confused? First you talk about decoding an array from an API and then about encoding your struct.

Comment: Please share your decoding code.

Comment: Question edited. I'm trying to both encode and decode, as I figured if one was supported out of the box the other should too. I also added the manual decoding code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `singleValueContainer` use `unkeyedContainer`, it's more robust. If you want to assign the array items to struct members you have to write a custom initializer anyway

```
struct Message: Codable {
    let user: String
    let content: String
    let date: String

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var arrayContainer = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        guard arrayContainer.count == 3 else { throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: arrayContainer, debugDescription: "The array must contain three items") }
        user = try arrayContainer.decode(String.self)
        content = try arrayContainer.decode(String.self)
        date = try arrayContainer.decode(String.self)           
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var arrayContainer = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try arrayContainer.encode(contentsOf: [user, content, date])
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s really nice. But what’s the use of `var intValue:Int ?` in the `CodingKey` protocol ? Sure it’s used for Array de/coding, but it’s sad not to be able to use in other structs